# Expected spy log to have been called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have created a simple JS **function** which i want to test but when i run it is showing error ***Expected spy log to have been called*** what am i doing wrong ?

**Function**

```js
function helloWorld() {
    console.log('hey');
}
```

**Test spec**

```
describe('Hello world', function () {
    it('says hello', function () {
        spyOn(console,'log').and.callThrough();
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not an error, it's a failed test. That's because you don't call the log function in your example, so the test "correctly" fails.

```js
describe('Hello world', function () {
  it('says hello', function () {
    spyOn(console,'log').and.callThrough();
    comp.helloWorld();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```